# xamarin ViewPager Android

Tags: c#, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

I was trying to create a Sliding-Tab-Layout. I followed this tutorial [Sliding Tab Layout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Rr0ZCvX_Zs&index=10&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l)
and it was great, but I wanted to Load Specific Layout in each `TabView`

I also want to make each one loaded, when I select it or scroll to it just like facebook application.

The reason is not to take so much time to load for each View in ViewPager
and there is the classes:

**SlidingTabStrip**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Util;

namespace SlidingTabLayoutTutorial
{
    public class SlidingTabStrip : LinearLayout
    {
        //Copy and paste from here................................................................
        private const int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
        private const byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0X26;
        private const int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
        private int[] INDICATOR_COLORS = { 0xffffff };
        private int[] DIVIDER_COLORS = { 0xffffff };

        private const int DEFAULT_DIVIDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 1;
        private const float DEFAULT_DIVIDER_HEIGHT = 0.5f;

        //Bottom border
        private int mBottomBorderThickness;
        private Paint mBottomBorderPaint;
        private int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;

        //Indicator
        private int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
        private Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

        //Divider
        private Paint mDividerPaint;
        private float mDividerHeight;

        //Selected position and offset
        private int mSelectedPosition;
        private float mSelectionOffset;

        //Tab colorizer
        private SlidingTabScrollView.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
        private SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;
        //Stop copy and paste here........................................................................

        //Constructors
        public SlidingTabStrip (Context context) : this(context, null)
        { }

        public SlidingTabStrip (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
            SetWillNotDraw(false);

            float density = Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

            TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
            context.Theme.ResolveAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.ColorForeground, outValue, true);
            int themeForeGround = outValue.Data;
            mDefaultBottomBorderColor = SetColorAlpha(themeForeGround, DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

            mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
            mDefaultTabColorizer.IndicatorColors = INDICATOR_COLORS;
            mDefaultTabColorizer.DividerColors = DIVIDER_COLORS;

            mBottomBorderThickness = (int)(DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
            mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
            mBottomBorderPaint.Color = GetColorFromInteger(0x1B729E); //Gray

            mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int)(SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
            mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();

            mDividerHeight = DEFAULT_DIVIDER_HEIGHT;
            mDividerPaint = new Paint();
            mDividerPaint.StrokeWidth = (int)(DEFAULT_DIVIDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);

        }

        public SlidingTabScrollView.TabColorizer CustomTabColorizer
        {
            set
            {
                mCustomTabColorizer = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public int [] SelectedIndicatorColors
        {
            set
            {
                mCustomTabColorizer = null;
                mDefaultTabColorizer.IndicatorColors = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public int [] DividerColors
        {
            set
            {
                mDefaultTabColorizer = null;
                mDefaultTabColorizer.DividerColors = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private Color GetColorFromInteger(int color)
        {
            return Color.Rgb(Color.GetRedComponent(color), Color.GetGreenComponent(color), Color.GetBlueComponent(color));
        }

        private int SetColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha)
        {
            return Color.Argb(alpha, Color.GetRedComponent(color), Color.GetGreenComponent(color), Color.GetBlueComponent(color));
        }

        public void OnViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset)
        {
            mSelectedPosition = position;
            mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            int height = Height;
            int tabCount = ChildCount;
            int dividerHeightPx = (int)(Math.Min(Math.Max(0f, mDividerHeight), 1f) * height);
            SlidingTabScrollView.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null ? mCustomTabColorizer : mDefaultTabColorizer;

            //Thick colored underline below the current selection
            if (tabCount > 0)
            {
                View selectedTitle = GetChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
                int left = selectedTitle.Left;
                int right = selectedTitle.Right;
                int color = tabColorizer.GetIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

                if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (tabCount - 1))
                {
                    int nextColor = tabColorizer.GetIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                    if (color != nextColor)
                    {
                        color = blendColor(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
                    }

                    View nextTitle = GetChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                    left = (int)(mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.Left + (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
                    right = (int)(mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.Right + (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
                }

                mSelectedIndicatorPaint.Color = GetColorFromInteger(color);

                canvas.DrawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right, height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);

                //Creat vertical dividers between tabs
                int separatorTop = (height - dividerHeightPx) / 2;
                for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount -1; i++)
                {
                    View child = GetChildAt(i);
                    mDividerPaint.Color = GetColorFromInteger(tabColorizer.GetDividerColor(i));
                    canvas.DrawLine(child.Right, separatorTop, child.Right, separatorTop + dividerHeightPx, mDividerPaint);
                }

                canvas.DrawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, Width, height, mBottomBorderPaint);
            }
        }

        private int blendColor(int color1, int color2, float ratio)
        {
            float inverseRatio = 1f - ratio;
            float r = (Color.GetRedComponent(color1) * ratio) + (Color.GetRedComponent(color2) * inverseRatio);
            float g = (Color.GetGreenComponent(color1) * ratio) + (Color.GetGreenComponent(color2) * inverseRatio);
            float b = (Color.GetBlueComponent(color1) * ratio) + (Color.GetBlueComponent(color2) * inverseRatio);

            return Color.Rgb((int)r, (int)g, (int)b);
        }

        private class SimpleTabColorizer : SlidingTabScrollView.TabColorizer
        {
            private int[] mIndicatorColors;
            private int[] mDividerColors;

            public int GetIndicatorColor(int position)
            {
                return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.Length];
            }

            public int GetDividerColor (int position)
            {
                return mDividerColors[position % mDividerColors.Length];
            }

            public int[] IndicatorColors
            {
                set { mIndicatorColors = value; }
            }

            public int[] DividerColors
            {
                set { mDividerColors = value; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SlidingTabScrollView**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace SlidingTabLayoutTutorial
{
    public class SlidingTabScrollView : HorizontalScrollView
    {

        private const int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 15;
        private const int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 15;
        private const int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 20;

        private int mTitleOffset;

        //private int mTabViewLayoutID;
        //private int mTabViewTextViewID;

        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

        private static SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

        private int mScrollState;

        public interface TabColorizer
        {
            int GetIndicatorColor(int position);
            int GetDividerColor(int position);
        }

        public SlidingTabScrollView(Context context) : this(context, null) { }

        public SlidingTabScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : this(context, attrs, 0) { }

        public SlidingTabScrollView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle) : base(context, attrs, defaultStyle)
        {
            //Disable the scroll bar
            HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;

            //Make sure the tab strips fill the view
            FillViewport = true;
            this.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#0078FF")); //Gray color

            mTitleOffset = (int)(TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);

            mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
            mTabStrip.WeightSum = 3;
            this.AddView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        }

        public TabColorizer CustomTabColorizer
        {
            set { mTabStrip.CustomTabColorizer = value; }
        }

        public int [] SelectedIndicatorColor
        {
            set { mTabStrip.SelectedIndicatorColors = value; }
        }

        public int [] DividerColors
        {
            set { mTabStrip.DividerColors = value; }
        }

        public ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener OnPageListener
        {
            set { mViewPagerPageChangeListener = value; }
        }

        public ViewPager ViewPager
        {
            set
            {
                mTabStrip.RemoveAllViews();

                mViewPager = value;
                if (value != null)
                {
                    value.PageSelected += value_PageSelected;
                    value.PageScrollStateChanged += value_PageScrollStateChanged;
                    value.PageScrolled += value_PageScrolled;
                    PopulateTabStrip();
                }
            }
        }

        void value_PageScrolled(object sender, ViewPager.PageScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            int tabCount = mTabStrip.ChildCount;

            if ((tabCount == 0) || (e.Position < 0) || (e.Position >= tabCount))
            {
                //if any of these conditions apply, return, no need to scroll
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.OnViewPagerPageChanged(e.Position, e.PositionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.GetChildAt(e.Position);

            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null ? (int)(e.Position * selectedTitle.Width) : 0);

            ScrollToTab(e.Position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null)
            {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.OnPageScrolled(e.Position, e.PositionOffset, e.PositionOffsetPixels);
            }

        }

        void value_PageScrollStateChanged(object sender, ViewPager.PageScrollStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            mScrollState = e.State;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null)
            {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.OnPageScrollStateChanged(e.State);
            }
        }

        void value_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.ScrollStateIdle)
            {
                mTabStrip.OnViewPagerPageChanged(e.Position, 0f);
                ScrollToTab(e.Position, 0);

            }

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null)
            {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.OnPageSelected(e.Position);
            }
        }

        private void PopulateTabStrip()
        {
            PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.Adapter;

            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.Count; i++)
            {
                TextView tabView = CreateDefaultTabView(Context);
                tabView.Text = ((SlidingTabsFragment.SamplePagerAdapter)adapter).GetHeaderTitle(i);
                tabView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                tabView.Tag = i;
                tabView.Click += tabView_Click;
                mTabStrip.AddView(tabView);
            }

        }

        void tabView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextView clickTab = (TextView)sender;
            int pageToScrollTo = (int)clickTab.Tag;
            mViewPager.CurrentItem = pageToScrollTo;
        }

        private TextView CreateDefaultTabView(Android.Content.Context context )
        {
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            textView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
            textView.Typeface = Android.Graphics.Typeface.Default;
            textView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MatchParent, 1);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Honeycomb)
            {
                TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
                Context.Theme.ResolveAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.SelectableItemBackground, outValue, false);
                textView.SetBackgroundResource(outValue.ResourceId);
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.IceCreamSandwich)
            {
                textView.SetAllCaps(true);
            }

            int padding = (int)(TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
            textView.SetPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

            return textView;
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();

            if (mViewPager != null)
            {
                ScrollToTab(mViewPager.CurrentItem, 0);
            }
        }

        private void ScrollToTab(int tabIndex, int extraOffset)
        {
            int tabCount = mTabStrip.ChildCount;

            if (tabCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabCount)
            {
               //No need to go further, dont scroll
                return;
            }

            View selectedChild = mTabStrip.GetChildAt(tabIndex);
            if (selectedChild != null)
            {
                int scrollAmountX = selectedChild.Left + extraOffset;

                if (tabIndex >0 || extraOffset > 0)
                {
                    scrollAmountX -= mTitleOffset;
                }

                this.ScrollTo(scrollAmountX, 0);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**SlidingTabsFragment**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;

namespace SlidingTabLayoutTutorial
{
    public class SlidingTabsFragment : Fragment
    {
        private SlidingTabScrollView mSlidingTabScrollView;
        private ViewPager mViewPager;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
        }
        public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            mSlidingTabScrollView = view.FindViewById<SlidingTabScrollView>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
            mViewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
            mViewPager.Adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter();
            mSlidingTabScrollView.ViewPager = mViewPager;
        }

        public class SamplePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string>();

            public SamplePagerAdapter() : base()
            {
                items.Add("Home");
                items.Add("Sell");
                items.Add("Rent");
            }

            public override int Count
            {
                get { return items.Count; }
            }

            public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object obj)
            {
                return view == obj;
            }

            public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.pager_item, container, false);
                container.AddView(view);

                TextView txtTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_title);
                int pos = position + 1;
                txtTitle.Text = pos.ToString();

                return view;
            }

            public string GetHeaderTitle (int position)
            {
                return items[position];
            }

            public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object obj)
            {
                container.RemoveView((View)obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.View;

namespace SlidingTabLayoutTutorial
{
    [Activity(Label = "Sliding Tab Layout", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/xs")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            SlidingTabsFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsFragment();
            transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
            transaction.Commit();

        }


        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.actionbar_main, menu);
            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add in your code something like this : (in `OnCreateView()` )

`position` => comes from the adapter..

```
  public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    view = (ViewGroup)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Page1, container, false);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    view = (ViewGroup)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Page2, container, false);
                    btn_forexample = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_forexample);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    view = (ViewGroup)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Page3, container, false);
                    break;
                default:
                    view = (ViewGroup)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DefaultPage, container, false);
                    break;
            }

            return view;
        }
```

Hope it helps ;)